# My goal is to add to a specific user's balance and dump the data back in but I get an error

Tags: python, json

Code that is suppose to add 10 to the current balance of that specific member:

```
import json

with open('users_balance.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file) 

member = "<@!702221444796383454>"
        
data['user_list']['user'][f'{member}']['balance'] += 10

with open('users_balance.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=2)
```

Json Info That the code is parsing:

```
{
  "user_list": [
    {
      "user": "<@!737747404048171043>",
      "balance": 50
    },
    {
      "user": "<@!672986823185661955>",
      "balance": 500
    },
    {
      "user": "<@!702221444796383454>",
      "balance": 90
    },
    {
      "user": "<@!483334860413599775>",
      "balance": 5043534645646
    },
    {
      "user": "<@!739240683642159236>",
      "balance": 1124131
    }
  ]
}
```

The error that appears when code is executed:

```
ERROR:
    data['user_list']['user'][f'{member}']['balance'] += 10
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: To find the user you want to modify you need to iterate through the list. Your `f{member}` syntax does not do anything remotely like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of dictionaries when you do `data['user_list']`. Your code fails because you are trying to index the list with `'user'`:

`data['user_list']['user']  # this is where it fails`

Because you have a list of dictionaries first you need to find the dictionary that contains the correct user data:

```
user_index = [i for i, d in enumerate(data['user_list']) if d['user'] == member][0]
```

You can find the index of the correct dictionary with this list comprehension. It compares the value for every dictionary for the key `'user'` with the variable `member` to find the index of the correct dictionary.

Then you can access the correct dictionary and increase the value there like this:

```
data['user_list'][user_index]['balance'] += 10
```

Note that this is slow and if the same user can appear multiple times you will have to loop over `user_index` instead of just taking the first (and only) element with `[0]`.

If you need to do this for many users it would be more efficient to convert `data['user_list']` to a dictionary where the keys are the users and the values are their balances and then update that.

Comment: How do I find the index for a certain user?

Comment: In the list comprehension replace the `member` in `if d['user'] == member` with the user you are looking for, the index of that user is then stored in the variable `user_index`.